# Service Module Loader:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, wildfly

Не могу подключиться к **базе** через **jdbc**

```
Product summary:
    - IDE: Eclipse
     - Build: Maven
     - Framework: Vaadin
     - Server: WildFly 10.0.0
```

Добавил все необходимые драйвера в папку lib и в dependency pom.xml

Создал класс `DatabaseHelper`

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DatabaseHelper implements Serializable {
private JDBCConnectionPool connectionPool = null;
private static ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("rts.data.databaseHelper");

public DatabaseHelper() {
    initConnectionPool();
}

private void initConnectionPool() {
    try {
        connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool("org.postgresql.Driver",bundle.getString("connectionUri") ,bundle.getString("userName"), bundle.getString("password"), 2, 2);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}   
public JDBCConnectionPool getConnectionPool() {
    return connectionPool;
}
}
```

создал свойства: `databaseHelper.properties`

```
connectionUri=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db.risk
userName=postgres
password=*******
```

Класс `DatabaseHelper` и `properties databaseHelper` находятся в одном package **rts.data**

Теперь запускаю WildFly в консольном окне получаю ошибки :

```
  18:00:56,015 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-6) Failed to define class rts.data.databaseHelper in Module "deployment.OR.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link rts/data/databaseHelper (Module "deployment.OR.war:main" from Service Module Loader): rts/data/databaseHelper (wrong name: rts/data/DatabaseHelper)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2640)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1501)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1465)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1419)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1419)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1361)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at rts.data.DatabaseHelper.<clinit>(DatabaseHelper.java:13)
    at rts.appUI.MyUI.init(MyUI.java:39)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:693)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:216)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1436)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:129)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Код 13 строки:**

```
 private static ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("rts.data.databaseHelper");
```

**Код 39 строки**

```
dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
```

Comment: `в консольном окне получаю ошибки : ...` тут чего-то не хватает

Comment: В любом случае если ошибка `NoClassDefFoundError` то, скорее всего код приводить нет необходимости. Нужно указать: 1) полные сведения об ошибке, 2) какой класс не найден, 3) где этот класс находится и почему Вы считаете что он доступен.

Comment: @defaultlocale упс., не добавил.

Comment: Почистите вопрос от ненужной информации (`LoginView` нигде в ошибке не упоминается, также как и СУБД). Укажите на какой строке возникает исключение (`rts.data.DatabaseHelper.<clinit>(DatabaseHelper.java:13)`)

Comment: Нет, трассировку стэка по ошибке лучше оставить полностью, она полезна.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, следующее:

1. Файл `databaseHelper.properties` должен находиться в папке `/src/main/resources/rts/data`, а не `src/main/java`. Каталог `java` предназначен для исходного кода.
2. Убедитесь, что `databaseHelper.properties` попадает в WAR-файл в результате сборки.
3. Попробуйте хотя бы на время отладки сделать `bundle` нестатичным и перенести инициализацию в конструктор:

   ```
   private ResourceBundle bundle;

   public DatabaseHelper() {
       bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("rts.data.databaseHelper");
       initConnectionPool();
   }
   ```

так, ошибки при инициализации `bundle` не окажут влияние на инициализацию класса и в логи попадет корневое исключение (если оно возникнет)

Comment: сделал как выше описано. Теперь у меня возникла другая исключения Null Pointer Exception

Comment: @Ulukmyrza не заметил, что `bundle` используется в `initConnectionPool`. Посмотрите обновленный конструктор `DatabaseHelper`